# Xamarin Forms - ResourceDictionary and <System:Uint32> value

Tags: xaml, uint64, uint32, uint

It's a simple question, maybe stupid, but I'm stuck from hours..

I have that in the XAML part:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <System:Uint32 x:Key="UintValue">50</System:Uint32>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Of course, to have the `<System>` type access, I had this line:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

However, I have an XAML parse Exception.. When I comment `<System:Uint32...</System:Uint32>` then it works. *#ButIDontHaveTheValue..*

**[There is a link to the doc of Uint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx)**

```
Type | Range              | Size                    | .NET Framework type
uint | 0 to 4,294,967,295 | Unsigned 32-bit integer | System.UInt32
```

**So If I'm right, then Uint32 is coming from System, so I have to reference it like System:Uint32 isn't?**

Thank for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit late but I will post an answer anyway. The type you need to import should be `UInt32` instead of `Uint32`, case sensitive. Anyway if you want to bind this value to a Margin or similar value you should use `String` instead because they could take more integers separated by a colon and they are a String.

```
<ContentPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
...
<System:UInt32 x:Key="sdsd">15</System:UInt32>
...
</ContentPage>
```